# For a geometric random variable Y, the probability distribution is $P(Y) = q^{(y-1)}p$

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, geometric-series

For a geometric random variable Y, the probability distribution is:-
$$ P(Y) = q^{(y-1)}  p $$

Using $$ E(Y) = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}yq^{y-1}p $$ with $$ p = 1 - q$$

--

$$ E[Y(Y-1)] = \sum_{y=1}^{\infty}y(y-1)q^{y-1}p$$
$$ = \sum_{y=0}^{\infty}y(y+1)q^{y}p $$

How is this change in equation possible with just adding one more term? I do not understand the steps in between that lead to this transformation. How could those two equations be equivalent?

I understand that for y = 0, the first term would result in 0.

Comment: Is it the last equality you do not understand ? It is just a change of variables $y'=y-1$, or equivalently $y=y'+1$.

Comment: Yes, the last equality. Wow. That is not obvious to me at all. Thanks.